# In Java, An exception thrown by us is not caught by the default handler? Right

Tags: java, exception

But then in the following program, when the exception is re-thrown in the catch statement, without the throws clause, no error is there??
How?

```
Class Throwdemo {
  static void demoproc(){
    try{
        throw new NullPoinerException ("demo");
    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught inside demoproc."); 
        throw e;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String Args[]){
    try[
        demoproc();
    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Recaught : " + e);
    }
}
}
```

THe output is

```
Caught inside demoproc.
Recaught : java.lang.NullPointerException: demo
```

Comment: Output looks just like one would expect. What is your question?

Comment: @Thilo, @Luzhin: May be OP wants to say that why it doesn't require to add `throws` in `demoproc()` method. [As far as I understand]

Comment: I mean, if a method can't handle an exception by itself, the Exception subclass has to be included in the throws clause, but the second time the exception is thrown there is no catch statement to catch it in the same method?

Comment: NullPointerException is an unchecked exception and thus need not be mentioned in throws clause.

Answer (score 5):

You only need `throws` clause for ***checked Exceptions***.

Comment: I.e.: You do not need to declare RuntimeExceptions (such as NullPointerExceptions) in the method signature (but you still can, if you want).

Answer (score 3):

Observe these lines:

```
public static void main(String Args[]){
    try[
```

The `try` has a bracket, not a brace.  Probably, you've been unsuccessfully compiling the program, and then re-running the old class file.

Answer (score 2):

Because `NullPoinerException` is a `RuntimeException`. It doesn't need a `throws` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to get what you meant be default handler. When the execption is thrown by

```
throw new NullPoinerException ("demo");
```

This is caught by the try catch block surrounding it.

Catch block in turn throws exception, which is caught by try catch block in main.

Hope this helps.

Edit after your comment: Also NullPoinerException exception is unchecked exception thus need not be mentioned as throws.